# Justify text in a div with width 100% - 60px

Tags: css, text-alignment, text-align, justify, text-justify

I have a

```
#menu {
  width: calc(100vw - 60px);
  left: 30px;
}
```

How can the words be justified in the available space?

I'm tryin the

```
text-align:justify
```

but it doesn't work.

https://jsfiddle.net/ju0mz9t0/1/

Comment: What *"4 menu voices"*? You have only text in the div.

Comment: @Paulie_D - I think he means "choices", not "voices".

Comment: Yes I meant choices sorry guys.

Comment: Either way...there are not 4 elements in the div...it's text node....and it will also depend on what is meant by "justify".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume you mean the text.  This is because `text-align: justify` doesn't justify the last line of a block of text.  One workaround is to add a css generated content item that acts like an inline text item but stretches the full width of the container like so:

```
#menu:after {
  content: '';
  display:inline-block;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```css
#menu{
font-family: Arial;
font-size:22px;
width: calc(100vw - 60px);
left: 30px;
text-align: justify;
text-justify: inter-word;
position:fixed;
}

#menu:after {
  content: '';
  display:inline-block;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="menu">
SS17 FW16/17 ABOUT STOCKISTS
</div>
```

Comment: @FedericoFerrari You're welcome.  Glad I could help.

Comment: hey. just as a side-question. i know that `text-justify: inter-word;` is not supported in chrome nor in firefox. is this something that would affect the outcome of your solution ?

Comment: @MihaiT It shouldn't affect it at all if the target text is English (or any language that separates words using spaces) as `text-align:justify` operates that way by default as far as I understand.  Ultimately, however, I don't really know.  I've never had to use `text-justify: inter-word;`.

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean something like this?

This solution uses `display: flex` and it's property `justify-content: space-between;`

Read more about flexbox [here](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

```css
#menu {
  display: flex;
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 22px;
  width: calc(100vw - 60px);
  left: 30px;
  text-align: justify;
  text-justify: inter-word;
  position: fixed;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

```html
<div id="menu">
  <span>SS17</span><span>FW16/17</span><span>ABOUT</span><span>STOCKISTS</span>
</div>
```

Comment: @FedericoFerrari This is probably a better approach.  Text nodes are very messy when it comes to styling.